# How can I make a node server public with port forwarding

Tags: node.js, express, portforwarding

I'm making a simple app that lets you download things from an express server but I can't seem to figure out how to make it public. I'd like to do it by port forwarding my router if possible.

I've already added the port (I've tried 3000 7777 and a few more) to the port forwarding setting in my router and even allowed the ports through my firewall and the server is listening on my IP(ipv4) and the port but still nothing.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you are testing it from within the network that the router provides, this could be the problem. Routers sometimes don't bother implementing the case where internal traffic accesses the public ip and port. Test it using a tethered phone connection. Let us know how it goes

Comment: I've tried that but it still doesn't work

Comment: Okay good. Next you'll want to keep checking each part in the chain. Have you verified your firewall tweaks are correct (try from another device on the network)?

Comment: This is gonna seem silly (maybe even insulting), but are you sure the internal IP you're forwarding to (the express server's local network ip) is correct?

Comment: (But yeah, the short answer is that it doesn't seem like you're missing something... it should just work the way you have described, which is why I'm asking about all these details)

Comment: Yea I checked all that and still nothing.I even tried disabling my firewall entirely.